# Remove ntfs-3g compression (both directory and filesystem)

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

[`man mkfs.ntfs`](https://manned.org/mkfs.ntfs.8) says:

> ```
>   -C, --enable-compression
>          Enable compression on the volume.
> ```

If I have a volume made with this option, how do I later disable compression?

Also, how do I disable compression on a per-folder basis, and have this propagate to folders which inherit from their parent?